# Is there a workaround to use TransformXML with Content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Since the retirement of classic content in Salesforce Marketing cloud, the AMPScript function TransformXML no longer works for new assets created in Content Builder (using it with XML/XSL from a DE for an order confirmation email).

Has anyone found a work-around that works? Trying to avoid using the Build Rowset options since our XML is rather complex with nesting and namespaces etc...

The following do not work:

Method One

Upload XML and XSL files to Content Builder
Attempt to use: `%%=TransformXML(ContentBlockById("xmlID"), ContentBlockById("xslID"))=%%`
Method fails because those files are not considered content blocks

Method Two

Copy/Paste XML and XSL files into separate Code Snippets
Attempt to use: `%%=TransformXML(ContentBlockById("xmlID"), ContentBlockById("xslID"))=%%`
Fails with the error: Failed to parse XML document. See inner exception for details.
​

Method Three

Import the XML and XSL into a data extension (example file included)

```
%%[ TransformXML(Lookup('TransformXMLTest', 'XML', 'ID', 1), Lookup('TransformXMLTest', 'XSL', 'ID', 1)) ]%%
```

Fails with the error:

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [this solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/399326/5202), in which you BASE-64 encode the XML and XSL before storing them in Content Builder.

In your case it'd be something like this:

```ampscript
%%[

set @xsl = Base64Decode(ContentBlockById("xmlID"), "UTF-8")
set @xml = Base64Decode(ContentBlockById("xslID"), "UTF-8")

]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(TransformXML(@xml,@xsl))=%%
```

**Reference:**

- [Base64Decode](https://ampscript.guide/Base64Decode)
- [TransformXML](https://ampscript.guide/TransformXML)
- [TreatAsContent](https://ampscript.guide/TreatAsContent)

**EDIT 2023-06-19**

Confirmed that this method does indeed work. And, to be honest, it is much easier to use AMPscript and the [BuildRowSetFromXML](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromxml) methods for building dynamic content.